# Implementing traits on boxed Fn trait generics leads to lifetime issues

Tags: generics, rust, closures, trait-objects

Something of a beginner at Rust here. I'm trying to implement a trait, `Ring`, for functions that map data types that map types implementing`Ring`s to themselves. `Ring` looks like this:

```rust
trait Ring {
    fn plus(&self, other: &Self) -> Self;
    fn times(&self, other: &Self) -> Self;
    fn negate(&self) -> Self;
}
```

And my attempted implementation looks like this:

```rust
impl <R: Ring> Ring for Box<dyn Fn(&R) -> R> {

    //(f+g)(a) = f(a) + g(a)
    fn plus(&self, other: &Self) -> Self {
        Box::new(move |x: &R| -> R {self(x).plus(&other(x))})
    }
    //(fg)(a) = f(g(a))
    fn times(&self, other: &Self) -> Self {
        Box::new(move |x: &R| -> R {self(&other(x))})
    }
    //(-f)(a) = -(f(a))
    fn negate(&self) -> Self {
        Box::new(move |a: &R| -> R {self(a).negate()})
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `Box<dyn Fn(&R) -> R` in place of the syntactically nicer `impl Fn(&R) -> R` because the compiler forbids using `impl Trait` here.

The error message provided is:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:73:9
   |
72 |     fn plus(&self, other: &Self) -> Self {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
73 |         Box::new(move |x: &R| -> R {self(x).plus(&other(x))})
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Some things I have tried in response:

i) Adding a generic lifetime annotation to the methods. This makes the `Ring` trait no longer recognize them as implementing the methods it needs to. Attempting to edit `Ring` itself to include these annotations produces an error message telling me that my lifetime name shadows a preexisting one.

ii) Boxing `dyn Fn(&R) -> R + 'static` in place of `dyn Fn(&R) -> R`, and annotating `self` as static as well. This produces a lifetime mismatch.

iii) Verifying that plus, times, and negate work as intended with no compiler errors when restated outside of the implementation block-- they do.

How can I ensure that the lifetime of `&self` is indeed as long as I need it to be?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't implement the trait unless you can change `Ring`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman This might work for my project, depending on what the change looks like: could you go into a little more detail about what would need to change?

Comment: One possible option is to take `self` instead of `self`.